# Cordova: Android SDK is not set up properly. Make sure that the Android SDK 'tools' and 'platform-tools' directories are in the PATH variable

Tags: android, apache-cordova, ionic3, cordova-plugin

Como corrigir este erro ao executar o comando: ionic cordova platform add android ?

```
ionic cordova platform add android
> cordova platform add android --save
Using cordova-fetch for cordova-android@7.1.1
Adding android project...
Creating Cordova project for the Android platform:
        Path: platforms\android
        Package: io.ionic.starter
        Name: wellfitapp
        Activity: MainActivity
        Android target: android-27
Android project created with cordova-android@7.1.1
Android Studio project detected
Android Studio project detected
Installing "cordova-plugin-advanced-http" for android
Plugin dependency "cordova-plugin-file@6.0.1" already fetched, using that version.
Installing "cordova-plugin-file" for android

The Android Persistent storage location now defaults to "Internal". Please check this plugin's README to see if your application needs any changes in its config.xml.

If this is a new application no changes are required.

If this is an update to an existing application that did not specify an "AndroidPersistentFileLocation" you may need to add:

      "<preference name="AndroidPersistentFileLocation" value="Compatibility" />"

to config.xml in order for the application to find previously stored files.

Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Installing "cordova-plugin-device" for android
Installing "cordova-plugin-facebook4" for android
config file res/values/facebookconnect.xml requested for changes not found at C:\projetos\wellfitapp\platforms\android\res\values\facebookconnect.xml, ignoring
config file res/values/facebookconnect.xml requested for changes not found at C:\projetos\wellfitapp\platforms\android\res\values\facebookconnect.xml, ignoring
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Dependent plugin "cordova-plugin-file" already installed on android.
Installing "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard" for android
Installing "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview" for android
Installing "cordova-plugin-splashscreen" for android
Installing "cordova-plugin-whitelist" for android

               This plugin is only applicable for versions of cordova-android greater than 4.0. If you have a previous platform version, you do *not* need this plugin since the whitelist will be built in.

Installing "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" for android
Plugin dependency "es6-promise-plugin@4.2.2" already fetched, using that version.
Installing "es6-promise-plugin" for android
Subproject Path: CordovaLib
Subproject Path: app
Installing "cordova-plugin-x-toast" for android
Installing "cordova-plugin-youtube-video-player" for android
Installing "cordova-sqlite-storage" for android
installing external dependencies via npm
npm install of external dependencies ok
Failed to install 'cordova-sqlite-storage': Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\projetos\wellfitapp\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:646:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:551:33)
    at Object.parseElementtreeSync (C:\projetos\wellfitapp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\util\xml-helpers.js:180:27)
    at new AndroidManifest (C:\projetos\wellfitapp\platforms\android\cordova\lib\AndroidManifest.js:29:20)
    at AndroidProject.getPackageName (C:\projetos\wellfitapp\platforms\android\cordova\lib\AndroidProject.js:99:12)
    at Api.addPlugin (C:\projetos\wellfitapp\platforms\android\cordova\Api.js:223:57)
    at handleInstall (C:\Users\Ramos\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\install.js:594:10)
    at C:\Users\Ramos\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\install.js:357:28
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\Ramos\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:787:54)
(node:8584) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\projetos\wellfitapp\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:646:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:551:33)
    at Object.parseElementtreeSync (C:\projetos\wellfitapp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\util\xml-helpers.js:180:27)
    at new AndroidManifest (C:\projetos\wellfitapp\platforms\android\cordova\lib\AndroidManifest.js:29:20)
    at AndroidProject.getPackageName (C:\projetos\wellfitapp\platforms\android\cordova\lib\AndroidProject.js:99:12)
    at Api.addPlugin (C:\projetos\wellfitapp\platforms\android\cordova\Api.js:223:57)
    at handleInstall (C:\Users\Ramos\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\install.js:594:10)
    at C:\Users\Ramos\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\plugman\install.js:357:28
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\Ramos\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\Ramos\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:816:30)
(node:8584) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:8584) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\Ramos\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:816:30)
```

Quando executo cordova info me dá o resultado a seguir:

```
Plugins:

cordova-plugin-advanced-http,cordova-plugin-device,cordova-plugin-facebook4,cordova-plugin-file,cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard,cordova-plugin-ionic-webview,cordova-plugin-splashscreen,cordova-plugin-whitelist,cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing,cordova-plugin-x-toast,cordova-plugin-youtube-video-player,cordova-sqlite-storage,es6-promise-plugin

Error retrieving Android platform information:
Android SDK is not set up properly. Make sure that the Android SDK 'tools' and 'platform-tools' directories are in the PATH variable.

Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
'android' n�o � reconhecido como um comando interno
ou externo, um programa oper�vel ou um arquivo em lotes.
```

**EDITADO::**

```
> cordova prepare android
cp: copyFileSync: could not write to dest file (code=ENOENT):C:\projetos\wellfitapp\platforms\android\res\xml\config.xml

Parsing C:\projetos\wellfitapp\platforms\android\res\xml\config.xml failed
(node:940) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\projetos\wellfitapp\platforms\android\res\xml\config.xml'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:646:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:551:33)
    at Object.parseElementtreeSync (C:\projetos\wellfitapp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\util\xml-helpers.js:180:27)
    at new ConfigParser (C:\projetos\wellfitapp\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\ConfigParser\ConfigParser.js:30:24)
    at updateConfigFilesFrom (C:\projetos\wellfitapp\platforms\android\cordova\lib\prepare.js:106:18)
    at Api.module.exports.prepare (C:\projetos\wellfitapp\platforms\android\cordova\lib\prepare.js:42:20)
    at Api.prepare (C:\projetos\wellfitapp\platforms\android\cordova\Api.js:192:45)
    at C:\Users\Ramos\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\src\cordova\prepare.js:106:36
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\Ramos\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:787:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\Ramos\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-lib\node_modules\q\q.js:816:30)
(node:940) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:940) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: Como está o seu arquivo de configuração? Fiz essa pergunta esses dias no SO-EN, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51478914/cordova-plugin-facebook4-how-to-use-it

Answer (score -1, accepted):

você precisa definir a variável `ANDROID_HOME` como variável de ambiente, sem a variável definida, o cordova não consegue executar o comando **android**.
Recomendo a leitura deste artigo: 
[Configurando ambiente android](https://producaodejogos.com/configurando-o-ambiente-de-desenvolvimento-android/)

Para verificar se a variável de ambiente foi definida, execute o comando no terminal:
**Para Linux ou macOS**

```
echo $ANDROID_HOME
```

**Para windows:**

```
android
```

O comando **android** deve funcionar em ambas as plataformas, se rodar o comando android e receber a mensagem de que o comando não foi encontrado, a variável não está definida.

Abraços